# Excel VBA read validation list into variable

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to find an Excel VBA code that reads validation list into a variable.

I'm using Excel 2010 version.

In the code below I'm dynamically setting up values using variable qNR, and appears in dropdown menu. Later I need to read values in validation list, remove or update certain values and set new values.

I cannot find any example code that reads validation list into a variable.

```
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:=qNR
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True

End With
```

Thank you!

Comment: Validation lists can't do all the things you would expect from a ListBox. Trying to make an Excel sheet function as a form is a frustrating experience. Use WinForms where you can. Maybe use Access instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming it's a list type ([validation type 3](http://office.microsoft.com/client/helppreview.aspx?AssetId=HV805556109990&lcid=1033&NS=EXCEL%2EDEV&Version=12&CTT=5&origin=HV080554600)), then `Debug.Print Range(yourRange).Validation.Formula1` should print out a list. So `Object.Validation.Formula1` would appear to work for you. See [here](http://office.microsoft.com/client/helppreview.aspx?AssetId=HV805545829990&lcid=1033&NS=EXCEL%2EDEV&Version=12&respos=0&CTT=1&queryid=17f74590%2D677f%2D4bbc%2D8e59%2Dacedf25e8f63) for more info.

Comment: Worked using Target.Validation.Formula1. Thanks you very much Aaron

Comment: Object.Validation.Formula1 returns a formula associated with a Validation object.  @malas, how do you print the list?  What is Target?

Comment: @Aaron Thomas Both links are broken